# Python - Why uid function is not deleting my e-mail sent?

Tags: python, imaplib

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to use `imaplib`. I want to delete a specific e-mail sent from my hotmail account. I found the e-mail, the code doensn't return error but the message is not deleted.

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap-mail.outlook.com')
mail.login('XXXXX@hotmail.com', 'XXXXX')
mail.select('Sent')
typ, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
control = 0
tam = len(data[0].split())
while control < tam:
    typ, data = mail.fetch(tam - control, '(RFC822)')
    if str(data).find("My Subject") != -1: #works
        mail.uid('STORE', str(tam - control) , '+FLAGS', '(\Deleted)') # doesn't work
        mail.expunge() # doesn't work
    control = control + 1
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use UIDs to fetch and delete mails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`IMAP4.uid()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.uid) expects a message UID, while you seem to be using a message number. Try this instead:

```
mail.store(str(tam - control), '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
mail.expunge()
```

Note that IMAP4 message numbers change as the mailbox changes; in particular, after an `EXPUNGE` command performs deletions the remaining messages are renumbered.